# MongoDB - Multiple sortable lists in one collection

Tags: mongodb, sorting, data-modeling

I have a collection storing movies and another collection storing genres. A movie can belong to multiple genres. A genre can have multiple movies. Movies are viewed as a list by genre. User has the ability to order the movies inside each genre list. One movie can be in difference places in each genre list.

Assumptions:

- Both genres and movies in a genre can grow to very large numbers.
- Movies are always read by genre sorted according to how it was ordered by the user.
- Order of a movie in a genre can change frequently.
- New movies and genres can be added at any time.

How I have currently modeled this data is as follows. The movie collection looks like

```
{ _id:"M1", name:"The Bucket List", genres: ["G3", "G2", "G4"], priorities: { "G3":0.42, "G2":0.25, "G4":0.75 } }
{ _id:"M1", name:"The Shawshank Redemption", genres: ["G1", "G4"], priorities: { "G4":0.1, "G1":0.2 } }
{ _id:"M1", name:"The Italian Job", genres: ["G1", "G6", "G5"], priorities: { "G5":0.5, "G1":, "G6":0.8 } }
```

The genre collection looks like

```
{ _id:"G1", name:"crime", moreFields:"..."}
{ _id:"G2", name:"adventure", moreFields:"..."}
{ _id:"G3", name:"comedy", moreFields:"..."}
{ _id:"G4", name:"drama", moreFields:"..."}
{ _id:"G5", name:"action", moreFields:"..."}
{ _id:"G6", name:"thriller", moreFields:"..."}
```

The `genres` property in movie document stores the genre id's in an array. The `priorities` property in the movie document stores the priority of the movie by the genre id in a dictionary. The priority is a number between 0 and 1. 0 is the top most item and 1 is the last item. When a movie X is moved to between another two movies A and B, the priority for movie X is changed to `(priority of B - priority of A)/2`. This allows changing the priority of a movie with no change to other movie documents.

To populate a the genre list view, the projection is done on the movie collection by `genres` array and sorting is done by `priorities` dictionary for the specific genre id. Something like

```
db.movies.find( {"genres":genre_id} ).sort( {"priorities." + genre_id: 1} );
```

This would work just fine. However the priorities cannot be indexed in mongodb since it is a dictionary.

The questions are

1. Given the priority not being indexed, in large data volumes of movies and genres will the sort perform badly
2. Is there a better way to model the data to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about if we design  movie collection as following

```
{ _id:"M1", name:"The Bucket List", genres_priorities: [{ gen:"G3", priorities : 0.42}
                                                  , { gen:"G2", priorities : 0.25}
                                                  , { gen:"G4", priorities : 0.75}
] }
```

and we can set 
    ensureIndex({genres_priorities.gen:1, genres_priorities.priorities:1})
the query 
   db.movies.find( {"genres":genre_id} ).sort( {genres_priorities.gen:1, genres_priorities.priorities:1})

Let me know what you think.